# нерабочее решение через Linq c#

Tags: c#, linq

Входными данными является строка, содержащая один из символов .!?;:() 
например: "a; fg x; x y;"

необходимо разделить эту строку по ; , после чего, избавиться от string.Empty и null значений, на выходе должно быть: {"a", " fg x", " x y"} 
вместо этого: {"a"}

как это реализовать с помощью Linq? нерабочая версия:

```
var text = "a; fg x; x y;";
char[] separators = {';','!','?','.',':','(',')'};
string[] sentences = text.Split(separators).Where(x => x != string.Empty && x != null).ToArray();
```

весь код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main() 
    {
       
        SplitIntoSentences("a; fg x; x y;");

    }   
    public static void SplitIntoSentences(string text)
    {
        text = text.ToLower();
        char[] separators = {';','!','?','.',':','(',')'};
        string[] sentences = text.Split(separators).Where(x => x != string.Empty && x != null).ToArray();;
        
        Console.Write("{0} ", sentences);
    }       
}
```

Comment: Если вам нужно убирать и пробельные строки из результата, то у `Split` есть перегрузка со [SplitOptions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringsplitoptions?view=netcore-3.1). Выберите `SplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`, он вам уберет пустые и пробельные строки

Comment: пробелы нужно оставить

Comment: `string[] sentences = text.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x=>x.Trim()).ToArray();`

Answer (score 3):

Запустил код на приведённом примере - отработало как надо

```
var text = "a; fg x; x y;";

char[] separators = { ';', '!', '?', '.', ':', '(', ')' };
string[] sentences = text.Split(separators).Where(x => x != string.Empty && x != null).ToArray();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Уточните вопрос или "не воспроизводится".

Comment: автор поди Trim() хочет сделать на результате.